# CRM 2013: Calling actions from javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I was trying to call action from javascript using the below function:

```
function ExecuteActionCreateProject(reason, entityId, entityName, requestName)
{
    // Creating the request XML for calling the Action
    var requestXML = ""
    requestXML += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
    requestXML += "  <s:Body>";
    requestXML += "    <Execute xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";
    requestXML += "      <request xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts\">";
    requestXML += "        <a:Parameters xmlns:b=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic\">";
    requestXML += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestXML += "            <b:key>Reason</b:key>";
    requestXML += "            <b:value i:type=\"c:string\" xmlns:c=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">"+reason+"</b:value>";
    requestXML += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestXML += "          <a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestXML += "            <b:key>Target</b:key>";
    requestXML += "            <b:value i:type=\"a:EntityReference\">";
    requestXML += "              <a:Id>"+entityId+"</a:Id>";
    requestXML += "              <a:LogicalName>"+entityName+"</a:LogicalName>";
    requestXML += "              <a:Name i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestXML += "            </b:value>";
    requestXML += "          </a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
    requestXML += "        </a:Parameters>";
    requestXML += "        <a:RequestId i:nil=\"true\" />";
    requestXML += "        <a:RequestName>"+requestName+"</a:RequestName>";
    requestXML += "      </request>";
    requestXML += "    </Execute>";
    requestXML += "  </s:Body>";
    requestXML += "</s:Envelope>";
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST", GetClientUrl(), false)
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationServic/Execute");
    req.send(requestXML);
    //Get the Resonse from the CRM Execute method
    var response = req.responseXML.xml;
}
```

I was able to pass function parameters and client URL successfully, however this is the response this I get:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The message with Action 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationServic/Execute' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).
        </faultstring>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Kindly advise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typo!

```xml
req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationServic/Execute");
```

"IOrganizationServic" needs an 'e' appended.

Are you using the SOAPLogger?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a helper framework I've developed - http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2013/10/custom-actions-walkthrough-for-net-and.html

Answer (score 0):

The function looks ok. I can’t see the actual call so ensure that all values are properly encoded before you send the request.
MS uses the following sample to encode the values. 
Personally, I would replace the concatenation (string buffer) of the XmlEncode value with an array buffer to boost the performance.

```
function loadAction() {
    var reason = XmlEncode("custom string");
    var entityId = XmlEncode(Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId());
    var entityName = "serviceappointment";
    var requestName = "new_entityname";
    //call function with encoded values ...
    ExecuteActionCreateProject(reason, entityId, entityName, requestName);
}


XmlEncode = function (strInput) {
  var c, XmlEncode = '';

  if (strInput == null) { return null; }
  if (strInput == '') { return ''; }

  for (var cnt = 0; cnt < strInput.length; cnt++) {
   c = strInput.charCodeAt(cnt);

   if (((c > 96) && (c < 123))  ||  
        ((c > 64) && (c < 91))  ||
          (c == 32)             ||
     ((c > 47) && (c < 58))     ||
       (c == 46)        ||
       (c == 44)        ||
       (c == 45)        ||
       (c == 95)) {
      XmlEncode = XmlEncode + String.fromCharCode(c);
       }
       else {
       XmlEncode = XmlEncode + '&#' + c + ';';
     }
  }

     return XmlEncode;
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand how to use your code to make my code run properly

Comment: Please explain more..what is the added value ? How this could lead to make it work ??

Comment: Can't say if this is what causing your issue but it's obvious that
you're missing xml encoding and you need to rule out this option.

Comment: I think there’s a mismatch with the request name argument you’re passing to the function. 
What request are you trying to execute ? is it "Create" ? if so then requestName should be equal to "Create" and not the entity name

Comment: I'm trying ti execute an action, so I am passing the action name to the requestname argument.

Comment: Ok. Check that the action is activated and that the entity name casing is correct. Also, enable tracing and lookup for more meaningful information about this error.
I’d also create another custom action to see if this behavior is consistent.